# import PEM public key with Web Crypto API

Tags: javascript, public-key-encryption, pem, webcrypto-api

I'm currently trying to import my publicKey in PEM format, but i have this error in my console: `>> Uncaught (in promise) Error``

Here my code:

```
async function importPEM(pemKey) {
    const pemHeader = '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----';
    const pemFooter = '-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----';
    const pemContents = pemKey.substring(pemHeader.length, pemKey.length - pemFooter.length);
    const pemArrayBuffer = Uint8Array.from(atob(pemContents), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

    const importAlgorithm = {
        name: 'RSA-OAEP',
        hash: {
            name: 'SHA-256'
        },
    };

    return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'spki',
        pemArrayBuffer,
        importAlgorithm,
        true,
        ['encrypt'],
    );
}
```